# Data based estimation of missing values

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, correlation, missing-data

I have problem at hand where I feel there should be an rather elegant solution to it, but at this point I have problems finding the right search terms or getting the first step towards the right direction.

**Basics:**
I have a high dimensional data space with D = 19 and have about 100 points in the space (100 measurements). With PCA and dimensionality estimation algorithms, I already confirmed that the latent space on which the points lie on is relatively low dimensional (max 5 dimensions or so). Therefore, I think in general it is not impossible what I am asking.

**The problem:**
Now, based on uncomplete measurements of a new point, I would like to estimate the missing values. The problem is that I do not know which values will be missing. Basically all combinations of missing values are (somewhat) similarly likely. -> I could have 1 missing value, 19 missing values or something in between. In a perfect world, the algorithm I am looking for not only gives an estimate of the missing values, but also some error measure.

To further illustrate, I attach you one image with the raw data. The x-axis shows the 19 individual measured parameters and the y axis gives the values of those parameters. You can see that the measurements are highly correlated. So even if I specify only one measurement/dimension I should be able to give a somewhat reliable estimation of the rest. 
[image: The x-axis shows the 19 individual measured parameters and the y axis gives the values of those parameters. You can see that the measurements are highly correlated. enter image description here]

Does anyone of you have any pointers for me? Any thoughts or advice would be really helpful!
Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: To clarify, each line in the plot represent bone length measurements of one animal. That explains the high correlation between values, as different animals (of different species) are similar, but not exactly the same. So now I would like to infer the bone lengths of the missing bones, using this dataset. And obviously it is quite arbitrary which bones will be found/available, therefore I don't want a model that is particular for a set of missing values.

Comment: I started playing around with "Expectation Maximization Imputation", which might be able to do the trick. Downsides as I understand so far are that I do not get any statistical confidence of the estimation and that overall I am mis-using the method a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The Right Way (TM) to handle missing data is to average (i.e., integrate) over the missing variables, given the values of any known variables. A Bayesian belief network is a formalization of this idea. If you can say more about what the variables are, I can say more about how to go about building a suitable belief network.

Comment: @Thomas OK, that helps a lot. My guess is that all 19 variables are related to all the other variables, without any causal direction. This is probably a bit of a mess unless you make some strong simplifying assumption such as: the variables are jointly Gaussian. Another simplifying assumption is that variables for bones which are not connected are independent if the variables for intermediate bones are known. Given that you have a small number of data, my advice is to try to make use of prior information as much as you can to set the parameters for the joint distribution.

Comment: Alright, I think the assumption of jointly Gaussian might be alright. For the other assumption I am not sure, as this way I would stop the "information" flow over multiple bones? Not sure if that is possible with what you are proposing, but could you introduce some sort of hidden/abstraction nodes. So given incomplete data one could still try to infer those nodes and those nodes in turn then would define all bone lengths. For example, one of those nodes could define the "size" of the animal. Then maybe 1-4 more nodes could be enough that capture other (smaller) variations.

Comment: @Thomas It is certainly meaningful to introduce latent (unobserved) variables. Aside from that, bear in mind that in the absence of observed values for intermediate variables, two variables connected through intermediates are generally (not always) dependent. My advice is to draw circles and lines (representing variables and relations between them) first and then derive an algebraic statement from that. There are many references which a web search will find. A random example which seems helpful in this context: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dpage/cs731/UndirectedModels.ppt